# How is an argument passed to the inner function

Tags: javascript, function

In the code below, can someone please explain how did `add5(2)` get interpreted as passing an argument `2` to `y` argument of the `inner` function?

```
var count = 0;

function makeAdder(x) {
  return function inner(y) {
    return x + y;
  };
}
var add5 = makeAdder(5);
count += add5(2);
```

Comment: calling `makeAdder` returns a function with a bound `x` argument, called `add5`. This is later called below with it's own `y` argument and the result returned. The key point here is that calling `makeAdder` returns another function.

Answer (score 0):

`makeAdder` is what is known as a 'higher order function' - essentially a function that returns a function. Higher order functions are also functions that accept functions as parameters, so any function that takes or returns another function is a higher order function.

In this case, its returning the function named `inner`, although the functions can also be anonymous.

Because `inner` is defined in the scope of `makeAdder`, the value of `x` is captured by `inner`, so that it can be used later when `inner` is actually called.

The return value from `makeAdder` is assigned to `add5`, so `add5` is now a variable holding a reference to the `inner` function. By adding the call operator (`()`) to `add5` you are calling the function assigned to `add5`, so `inner` is now called with `2` as the value of `y`, and `x` is the value captured in the call to `makeAdder`, so `5`.  `5 + 2` = `7`.